# Can I make Python 2.5 exit on ctrl-D in Windows instead of ctrl-Z?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.5

I'm used to ending the python interactive interpreter using Ctrl-d using Linux and OS X.  On windows though, you have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then enter.  Is there any way to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ctrl-d works to exit from [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) 
(installed by [python(x,y)](https://python-xy.github.io/) package).

- OS: WinXP
- Python version:  2.5.4

---

**Edit:  I've been informed in the comments by the OP, Jason Baker, that Ctrl-d functionality on Windows OSes is made possible by the [PyReadline](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline/1.3.svn) package**:  "The pyreadline package is a python implementation of GNU readline functionality it is based on the ctypes based UNC readline package by Gary Bishop. It is not complete. It has been tested for use with windows 2000 and windows xp."

---

Since you're accustomed to *nix you may like that IPython also offers *nix-like shell functionality without using something like Cygwin...

- Proper bash-like tab completion.
- Use of / instead of \, everywhere
- Persistent %bookmark's
- %macro
- %store. Especially when used with macros and aliases.
- cd -. (easily jump around directory history). Directory history persists across sessions.
- %env (see cookbook)
- Shadow history - %hist and %rep (see cookbook)
- %mglob
- Expansion of $python_variables in system commands
- var = !ls -la (capture command output to handy string lists)

Comment: Why not just simply use *nix ? ;)

Comment: I wish I had that option becomingGuru.  :(

Comment: It requires the pyreadlines library:  http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/PyReadline/Intro  If you update your answer to say that, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>** on windows.

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>** is a [windows-specific control char that prints EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_file). On *nix, it is typically **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>**. That's the reason for the difference.

You *can*, however, train yourself to use `exit()`, which is cross-platform.

Comment: The python that's installed in Cygwin works with ctrl-d.  However, if I change it over to my windows install of Python, ctrl-d doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That is lame (not your answer), I use Julia language and I can CTRL-D to exit the REPL in Linux and Windows, I just can't believe Guido couldn't figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the key set that Idle should be using.

1. Under Options->"Configure IDLE..."
   go to the "Keys" tab.
2. On the right you can select the
       "IDLE Classic Unix" key set.

Comment: That if you're using IDLE (which you shouldn't anyway given its high suckage level)

Comment: nosklo, Care to elaborate why IDLE sucks? Never felt that way.

Comment: second the question from becomingGuru: why IDLE sucks?

Answer (score 0):

Run Cygwin Python if windowisms are bothering you...  Unless what you are doing depends on pywin32 that is.

Comment: The problem with this is that AFAIK, I can run Windows python anywhere including Cygwin.  I can run Cygwin Python only in Cygwin.